# Why can't I see my new harddrive on my Ubuntu box?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

I installed my new drive and put Ubuntu server on it. It was working fine except ubuntu server was a bit to raw for me. So, then I decided to go back to my old drive and use the new drive as a second drive (the old OS was still on the old drive). The old ubuntu loads fine but it cannot see the new drive.  I have tried putting the second dirve in all the SATA ports I have and I can never seem to see the drive.?

I run the following command to try and reformat it:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

and I get the following error:

```
Unable to open /dev/sdb
```

I do not have to set any physical pins to let it know it should be the second drive right? Its not like the old IDE days. Is there a certain order to the SATA ports on the board?

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated...

Comment: What does "fdisk -l" say about what drives are seen in the system?

Comment: Thanks for everyones help. You all had really good suggestions and I feal like a complete idiot for what it turned out to be. The power connection on the drive was loose! Once I got power to the drive things became much easier! Imagine that... 

Anyway I guess on the positive side is that I learned a lot about Linux drives!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
fdisk -l
```

To list all disks and partitions, you could also check
the boot log and see if the disk is detected there.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: *sudo* may have also been the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a certain order to the SATA ports, at least on the boards I've seen so far. The second disk might not show up as /dev/sdb but as /dev/sdc or /dev/sdd if you have 4 ports. But then, there might also be a problem with the disk itself.

Comment: Would this happen if we disable the "APU SATA ports" when not using an APU processor with integrated graphics?

Answer (score 1):

A crude but information rich method of checking for your drive... does going through the kernel output show your drive being listed?

```
dmesg | less
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous have posted, you need to make sure you are pointing to the right disk...maybe look at gparted to see if the disk shows up?

this link might help > [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) <

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Also check out **dmesg** to see what's happening as the system tries to initialize it.  Is it even recognized in BIOS?  If you can hot-plug it while the system is running, do `tail -f /var/log/messages` to see what's happening as you plug it in (then ctrl+C to end).

Comment: I guess by your suggestion that hot-plugging a SATA drive is safe?

Comment: http://linux-ata.org/software-status.html#hotplug.  Basically, your drive controller needs AHCI